# how to fix parrot os 4.4 sudo confilict when using sudo apt-get update

Tags: debian

$sudo apt-get update

Fetched 16.3 MB in 10min 30s (25.8 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Conflicting distribution: http://archive.parrotsec.org/parrot stable InRelease (expected stable but got rolling)
W: Conflicting distribution: http://matojo.unizar.es/parrot parrot InRelease (expected parrot but got rolling)
W: Conflicting distribution: http://deb.parrotsec.org/parrot stable InRelease (expected stable but got rolling)

Answer (score 0):

Please kindly look the [Documentation](https://docs.parrotlinux.org/faq/#how-do-i-upgrade-my-system) regarding how to upgrade the system.`sudo apt-get update`
has been long gone!

**Always use**

```
sudo parrot-upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```